# Can't get known from /var/lib/docker with 'gogs docker image'. Where is the repository path of Docker on raspberry pi?

Tags: git, docker, raspberry-pi, gogs

My raspberry pi runs a '**git repo docker image**' as a server and the docker image is commonly known as '**gogs docker**'.

I use this command line to check a folder which has been uploaded via `git push`

```
root@raspberrypi:/var/lib/docker# tree | grep <folder name>
```

There is nothing after this command.

I do mount volume to a path and I run `git push` and `git pull` perfectly.

Gogs has a webpage. I can see those folders and files I have uploaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inspect the container to find where are the files on the host that are associated with the container

1. Find the container name `docker ps`
2. Use `docker inspect <container name>` to find where are the files related to the container.

Depending on how the volumes and the container was created, you can see the folder associated with the base image as

```
docker inspect --format '{{.GraphDriver.Data.MergedDir }}' <container name>
```

or the mounted volumes as:

```
docker inspect --format "{{ range .Mounts }}{{ .Source }}{{ end }}" <container name>
```